# How to find different time intervals in r

Tags: r, datetime, xts

I have a vector of dates that looks like this:

`"2017-01-05 08:40:00 COT" "2017-01-05 08:50:00 COT" "2017-01-05 09:00:00 COT" "2017-01-05 09:10:00 COT" "2017-01-05 10:30:00 COT" "2017-01-05 10:40:00 COT" "2017-01-05 10:50:00 COT" "2017-01-05 11:00:00 COT" "2017-01-05 11:10:00 COT" "2017-01-05 11:20:00 COT" "2017-01-05 11:30:00 COT" "2017-01-05 11:40:00 COT""2017-01-05 11:50:00 COT" "2017-01-05 12:00:00 COT" "2017-01-05 12:10:00 COT" "2017-01-05 12:20:00 COT" "2017-01-05 12:30:00 COT" "2017-01-05 12:40:00 COT" "2017-01-05 12:50:00 COT" "2017-01-05 13:00:00 COT" "2017-01-05 13:10:00 COT" "2017-01-05 13:20:00 COT" "2017-01-05 13:30:00 COT" "2017-01-05 13:40:00 COT""2017-01-05 13:50:00 COT" "2017-01-05 14:00:00 COT" "2017-01-05 14:10:00 COT" "2017-01-05 14:20:00 COT" "2017-01-05 14:30:00 COT" "2017-01-05 14:40:00 COT" "2017-01-05 14:50:00 COT" "2017-01-05 15:00:00 COT"`

and are declare as POSIXct. I need to find the start and end time of the different time intervals in this vector. For this dates there are 2 time intervals: From `"2017-01-05 08:40:00 COT"` to `"2017-01-05 09:10:00 COT"` and from `"2017-01-05 10:30:00 COT"` to `"2017-01-05 15:00:00 COT"`.

I have tried the command range(data) but i get the starting date and the end date of the whole vector and not the different intervals. Hope someone can help

Comment: How are you defining the different intervals? Anything not 10mins different? Check out `diff(vecdates)` to check the differences between consecutive values.

Comment: @thelatemail yeah anything not 10 mins

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using some differences between the times to find the break points in your vector, which I've called `tx` (code to create below): As you can see, the results split into `8:40` to `9:10` and then `10:30` to the end.

```
diff(tx)
#Time differences in mins
#[1] 10 10 10 80 10 10 10

cumsum(c(FALSE, diff(tx)!=10))
#[1] 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1

split(tx, cumsum(c(FALSE, diff(tx)!=10)))
#$`0`
#[1] "2017-01-05 08:40:00 COT" "2017-01-05 08:50:00 COT" "2017-01-05 09:00:00 COT" "2017-01-05 09:10:00 COT"
#
#$`1`
#[1] "2017-01-05 10:30:00 COT" "2017-01-05 10:40:00 COT" "2017-01-05 10:50:00 COT" "2017-01-05 11:00:00 COT"
```

Where `tx` was:

```
tx <- structure(c(1483623600, 1483624200, 1483624800, 1483625400, 1483630200, 
1483630800, 1483631400, 1483632000), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
), tzone = "America/Bogota")
```

Comment: almost works perfect, but the last date of every "correct" interval is going to the next one. The `cumsum(c(FALSE, diff(tx)!=10))` works perfect, but the `split(tx, cumsum(c(FALSE, diff(tx)!=10)))` doesn't

Comment: @alejandroandrade - I don't know how that's possible - `split` just divides into groups based on the `cumsum` values. If one works, the other should too.

Comment: my bad i was missing the `FALSE`. Thanks for the answer

Comment: When using function diff, lets say I want the difference in hours, seconds etc, how can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you put all your dates in a vector called 'dates' you could do something like the following

```
Ranges <- cut(dates, breaks = "2 hours")
```

Comment: It works for 2 hours but i need it for 10 minutes and to be honest the answer from @thelatemail solves it perfectly. anyway thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you substitute your text in this input strategy you get a vector of datetimes:

```
 dat <- as.POSIXct( scan(text=' ... ',quote="\"",what="") )
 # Don't use spaces flanking the ellipsis
```

Then you could use findInterval to classify the dates and select one with the interval designation you desire, 1 and 3 in your case.

```
 Breaks <- scan(text='"2017-01-05 08:40:00 COT","2017-01-05 09:10:00 COT","2017-01-05 10:30:00 COT" , "2017-01-05 15:00:00 COT"', sep=",", what="")
# Read 4 items
findInterval(dat,  as.POSIXct(Breaks ) )
# [1] 1 1 1 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 4
```

Comment: You seem to be getting 4 intervals here instead of 2

Comment: And i would have to now the intervals before doing it and i actually have 10.000 dates so its not automatic. Thanks anyway